# Parse YAML file using its contents

Tags: r, yaml

I have a YAML file named JJ_model.yaml whose contents are as below:

```
author : JJ  
train_data_source : clean_train.csv
test_data_source : clean_test.csv
model_type : RF
RF:
    n_estimators : 10
    criterion : 'gini'
    max_features : 'auto'
    max_depth : 2
    n_jobs : 1
SVM:
    kernel : 'rbf'
    degree : 3
    gamma : 'auto'
    tol : 0.001
```

The `model_type` field is `RF` in this case. I want to pick up the contents of this YAML file using the `R` `yaml` package and in particular pick up the parameters for the `RF` in this case as opposed to `SVM`.

I tried doing the following but can't get it to work:

```
# read in and parse the yaml file
parsed_model_yaml <- yaml::yaml.load_file(input = file.path(wd_model_spec
                                                            , "JJ"
                                                            , "JJ_model.yaml"))
# This explicit reference works
test              <- parsed_model_yaml$RF$n_estimators
# This throws an error '$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors'
test_meta_parse   <- parsed_model_yaml$model_type$`parse(parsed_model_yaml$model_type)``
```

Could anyone please explain how to obtain the `model_type` without explicitly passing in the `RF` reference explicitly but getting it from the YAML contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another case of `fortune(312)`

> The problem here is that the $ notation is a magical shortcut and like any other magic if used incorrectly is likely to do the programmatic
>   equivalent of turning yourself into a toad.
>      -- Greg Snow (in response to a user that wanted to access a column whose name is stored in y via x$y rather than x[[y]])
>         R-help (February 2012)

Use `[[` not `$` where you need to:

```
parsed_model_yaml[[parsed_model_yaml$model_type]]$n_estimators
```

or make a helper function

```
estimators <- function(l) l[[l[['model_type']]]][['n_estimators']]

estimators(parsed_model_yaml)

# 10
```

(It would appear you might want to create an object class to hold your data and some standard extractor functions....)

Comment: That is great @mnel. I will accept this answer. Could you please put up an example of the Object class for this simple case - so that I can learn and extend from it?

Comment: @user4687531. No. Have a read of http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html or something similar.